# Kotlin - app crashes on start up at ObjectInputStream line

Tags: kotlin

My app crashes on startup at the ObjectInputStream line and I am unsure why this is the case, it calls upon the openInputFile command above it to get the file needed, but crashes the whole problem on startup.

I have tried removing activity tags from the line but nothing has worked as of yet

```
        private fun loadList() {
            try {
        val fileInputStream = activity?.openFileInput("starWarsList.dat")
        val objectInputStream = ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream)

        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        val list = objectInputStream.readObject() as? MutableList<StarWarsItem>
        if (list != null) {
            adapter.list = list
        }
        objectInputStream.close()
        fileInputStream?.close()
    } catch (e: java.io.FileNotFoundException) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "no existing list found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

The end result is meant to be the application loading properly, so I am able to work through the rest of my project, but as mentioned above, the app crashes on startup at this line.

Any input at all would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
The error is received on start up

```
2019-02-11 08:14:51.432 19116-19116/com.example.assignment E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.assignment, PID: 19116
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:503)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
     Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2344)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2813)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:804)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:301)
        at com.example.assignment.StarWarsList.loadList(StarWarsList.kt:52)
        at com.example.assignment.StarWarsList.onActivityCreated(StarWarsList.kt:46)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2460)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1483)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3269)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:620)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1391)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:2937)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) 
2019-02-11 08:14:51.513 19116-19116/com.example.assignment I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 19116 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Where is stacktrace?

Comment: @Cililing I’m not familiar with stacktrace?

Comment: @lg99 The stack trace looks like a list of filenames/errors, and should appear as the error message in the output. You say that your program crashes on the `ObjectOutputStream` line, however your snippet doesn't contain this line.

Comment: @Matt oh my mistake! I meant the ObjectInputStream, will edit the question now, was in a rush for work so apologies

Comment: Since the code you have provided isn't runnable on its own, and you haven't yet provided a stacktrace, or even an error message, there isn't really too much that can be done to help. Could you please edit your question?

Comment: @Matt edited the question to show error message

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an empty file with nothing to serialize.  I suggest dumping the binary contents of the `.dat` file, or its length, before reading it.

If it is not valid, replace it with a valid default.

Comment: Could you further explain what you mean by dumping the file's binary contents?

Comment: Using the input stream, not the object stream, read the file length and write it to your debug log.  From your stack trace, it seems the file is empty.  If that is the case, the problem is with your code that created the file.  Maybe you wrote the file once, before you added members to your class.